# Make bigger text input in bootstrap form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show a bigger input text for my form like the `<textarea rows="3"></textarea>` does, so the input text be wrapped inside the box. Whatever I have tried, isn't working. I tried add a css class with `height` attribute but it doesnt working the way I want. I tried [this](http://www.bootply.com/c4NcNR03Wo) with no successs.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputName" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Info</label>
       <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4">                      

         <input type="text" class="form-control myInput" name="info" required>
         <textarea rows="3"></textarea>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use input[type="text"] as the selector and change the font-size.

```
input[type="text"] {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the game maybe but I was successful with this:

```
<textarea class="text-area text-box multi-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Maximum = 2045 characters" data-val-length-max="2045" id="info" name="info" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
```